# subscr_payment using paypal ipn simulator

Tags: php, paypal

The paypal IPN simulator "currently" (As in I'm assuming never will) does not have functionality to test the `subscr_payment` payment option, this is really putting a dead hault in my project. I've read that I can just create a button that simulates this, but I don't have a clue how and after looking I can't find any information on it.

I'm creating a subscription based system for hosting a special type of website, I have everything done besides for the subscription model now and it seems like it's going to be the hardest part.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely possible to test recurring billing with Paypal.

There are multiple ways possible for this.

One is the paypal subscribe button and another way (which i have used) is via a subscription form.

For the subscribe button you can refer this [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/), it contains all the information you need to setup this.

For second method, you need to create a [form](https://www.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside) and place all the required variable in that form.

All the required variables are listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this workaround will help you. From within the PayPal developer site, you can go to the IPN simulator, select Transaction Type as Web Accept, click Show All Fields. You can then edit txn_type to be subscr_payment, subscr_signup, etc.

It's not perfect, as it doesn't give you all of the variables, but you can put info in other entries, and use a logical to determine whether or not the correct entry exists.

Do one test subscription, so that you have the values, and then work from there.